# Accessing a property/field on record type yields an IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5, indexoutofrangeexception

I am developing .Net 5.0 console application in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition on Windows 7.

When evaluating this C# code:
`int weirdIndex = child.Depth - 1;` or similarly `int weirdIndex = child._depth - 1;` an IndexOutOfRangeException gets thrown.

`child` is of record type `Step`, which has a private field `_depth` as well as a public getter `Depth`. Here is an extract of this record:

```
record Step
{
    /* a bunch of logic */

    private readonly int _depth;
    public int Depth => _depth;
}
```

I tried to use `struct` instead of `record` type, but it didn't fix the problem.

`weirdIndex` later is used to access an array, but the bounds are perfectly fine. Here is an extract from the function where `weirdIndex` is used:

```
foreach (var child in AllFather.Children)
    levels[child.Depth - 1][levelPtrs[child.Depth - 1]] = child.Sum.ToString();
    int weirdIndex = child._depth - 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Just separating the lines");
    levelPtrs[weirdIndex] = levelPtrs[weirdIndex] + 1;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the situation:
[image: a screenshot of Debug Window]

I want to point out that the message `Just separating the lines` actually appears in the Console twice before the Exception is thrown.

I tried evaluating the following expressions in the Watch 1 of the Debug Window, and everything had expected values:

```
Expression                 | Value
----------------------------------
levelPtrs[0]               | 2
child.Depth - 1            | 0
levelPtrs[child.Depth - 1] | 2
```

I quickly read [IndexOutOfRangeException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0) reference by Microsoft, and then also found this thread on StackOverflow: [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f), but neithere of them seem to adress the issue I'm having, as far as my understanding goes.

I am very confused and would really appreciate some help. What am I missing? Is this some kind of bug by any chance?

EDIT: `levels` is of type `string[][]`, `levelPtrs` is of type `int[]`, and `AllFather.Children` is of type `Step[]`.

EDIT: I put all the code in public GitLab repo under the branch "indexoutofrangeexception" in case somebody would like to see the whole codebase. It's not big, but quite noisy. Here is the repo: https://gitlab.com/wizardsanimals/funny-problems .

Comment: Strange indeed. `levelPtrs` is a nornal .NET array or is it a type with indexer by any chance? Do you reproduce the exception when you assign 3 to `levelPtrs[0]` in immediate window?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek , levelPtrs is a normal .Net array, int[] to be specific. I just did what you suggested and yes, the exception occurs anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see anything else that could cause a problem unless there is another thread changing the size of `levelPtrs` concurrently. Could you provide a minimal reproducible sample? I guess you might find the root cause on your way to isolate the problem.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful - I'd also suggest updating to VS2022 and .NET 6...

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek , I recall that threading was mentioned by Microsoft as a possible cause of the problem, but I doubt it's the case. Even though I know very little about threading, the whole project is just one file of logic — Step.cs . I set up a repo if you want to check out the code. For now, I found a better way to do what I was trying to do, later I will come back to this issue. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Then your code evaluates to levels[0][2] = child.Sum.ToString();. My guess is levels[0] is an array that has not index 2

Comment: @FyodorVolik Hi FyodorVolik, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Done. Thanks for just a reminder =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jalepi pointed out in the comments, levels[0] indeed is an array that has not index 2, as it only has a length of 2. That's the reason the exception was thrown.

On line 39 though, not 41. I don't know why Visual Studio decided that the line "`int weirdIndex = ...`" was the issue, I think it shouldn't have done so. Perhaps it was trying to help.

Thanks everybody for your comments. Moral of the story: check code both below and ABOVE when the cause of exception is unclear.